# Why is Microsoft Dynamics CRM so slow in my environment?

Tags: sql-server, performance, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm working on an application that uses Microsoft Dynamics CRM.  The CRM runs in a VM.  CRM has its SQL database running on the very same VM.  Alongside that CRM SQL database is a separate database used for parts of the application that don't directly use CRM.

Operations that query the non-CRM SQL database are lightning-fast, but operations that query CRM are molasses slow in the application.

In spite of this, queries run from SSMS on both the CRM and non-CRM SQL databases seem to be equally fast.

This seems to suggest that there is some aspect of my Dynamics CRM Server that is not performing well and needs to be tuned, but it isn't the SQL component?

How can I find what is make Dynamics CRM so slow?

Comment: How is the connection set up towards the CRM server? While not entirely certain, my first guess would be how you're reading the data from the CR service (I'm assuming you're doing so via the web service). The second guess would be the set up of your database.

Comment: From my limited exposure working on it for about 3-6 months about 8 years ago, Dynamics CRM suffered the same problem that Sharepoint does: it's a dynamic schema database, which are [known](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856222/whats-the-attraction-of-schemaless-database-systems) to have [issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66385/dynamic-database-schema).  I could certainly be mistaken, however, it's been a long time.

Comment: @KonradViltersten, can you tell me where in the settings I can see the connection set up you're referring to?

Comment: Developer's resources tab has the option listing all the three (or is it four now?) endpoints that you can access. I'm talking about the odata one, the one that is the actual web service where you fetch the data. We're talking C# code that reads from the CRM, right? Or am I misunderstanding your issue, maybe? How did you create the reference to the web service? Do you have a WCF client generated for you?

Comment: Can you share details about how you are accessing CRM?

Comment: @BaconBits: CRM does not have a schema-less or dynamic schema database. Its schema is extensible, but at the same time stays strictly relational. In general its tables and standard views perform as can be expected of common SQL Server databases.

Comment: If this question is not appropriate here, can we get it moved over to "Server Fault"?